# Can't enter space in textfield using forced uppercase textfield-formatter add-on in Vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, textfield, vaadin8

With the [TextField Formatter add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/textfield-formatter) for Vaadin 8, I can do the following to allow only upper-case characters:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.setBlocks(dataLen);
if (format[1].equalsIgnoreCase("UPPER"))
    options.setForceCase(ForceCase.UPPER);
new CustomStringBlockFormatter(options).extend(field);
```

However, after setting forced uppercase I can't enter space characters any longer. Does anyone how I can allow spaces as well as forced upper case characters?

Comment: Options nor CustomStringBlockFormatter are Vaadin classes. Could yoiu add more background and context info to your question?

Comment: I'm trying to force a textfield to accept uppercase entries from the users. if I don't call options.setForceCase(ForceCase.UPPER); everything is fine, just that the entries won't be in uppercase. Once i call that. all entries are in uppercase but user can't enter space. Did i missed out anything?

Comment: Are you using this add-on https://vaadin.com/directory/component/textfield-formatter ?

Comment: import org.vaadin.textfieldformatter.CustomStringBlockFormatter; I think so

Answer (score 3):

The TextField Formatter add-on doesn't support arbitrary groupings.The `setBlocks` in method in `Options` determines the fixed space-separated groups, so you can specify e.g. `options.setBlocks(3,3,2)` to allow entering text in the format of `XXX XXX XX`. If you want to allow only capitals, but spaces allowed in the middle in any position, like so that both `HELLO WORLD` and `HI WORLD` are allowed, you can use a CSS trick to set the letters print in all uppercase. Add the following rule in your theme `.scss` file:

```
  input.upper-textfield {
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
```

and define your `TextField` without a formatter, like this:

```
  TextField textField = new TextField("only upper");
  textField.setStyleName("upper-textfield");
  textField.setMaxLength(dataLen);
```

Now you just need to remember to change the text to uppercase in Java as well when you read it:

```
  String value = textField.getValue();
  if (value != null) {
    value = value.toUpperCase();
  }
```